# WCF Rest Service - Publishing issue

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I just recently posted my first WCF Rest service. It works great so far. Yesterday a request came in to alter something in the database table that houses the entries that come in to us via this service. Since the contract wasn't changing, it was basically a change to the insert within the datalayer, I assumed this change could be implemented easily. So I modified the insert, recompiled the code and republished the site/service.

The next time we received a request, it did not perform my updated insert, but rather the old version from the prior build. I thought perhaps I screwed up something compiling, so I recompiled and posted again. But ended with the same result.

Has anyone seen this happen before? How is this possible? Assuming I must be overlooking something minor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the DNS pointing to another server hosting an older, outdated version of the process that was suppose to have been decommissioned.